# aws cli autoscaling command doesn't return to shell promot

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, zsh, aws-cli

In Macbook pro, iterm2 with aws cli, shell zsh.

When running below command, the shell goes to an empty screen with "(END)" on the top left corn. I have to press "q" to exit to get back to shell prompt.

```
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name xxx --desired-capacity 1
```

This is very annoying. How can I change it so that the command just return back to normal shell promot?

Not all aws cli command has this same behavior. Like "aws s3 ls" runs ok.

Thanks.

Comment: There seem to be some issue on your end. I tested the command on `zsh` right now and haven't observed any problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AWS CLI v2 has the option to specify a **pager** to handle output that goes longer than one screen.

If you wish to display all output with no pagination, edit the `~.aws/config` file and insert:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

See: [AWS CLI version 2 uses a paging program for all output by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-output-pager)

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is it. I upgraded to cli 2.0. I was suspecting similar. I made an alias of less with -FX flag but it didn't work. Change this setting solved it.

Comment: Oh... this was so annoying! I upgraded to CLI2 for making some of the EMR commands work and it brought in this paging thing by default.